# Brick Breaker in Unity w json data input

Tags: json, unity-game-engine

I'm making a brick breaker game in Unity2D, but was told to make the bricks dynamic instead of dragging in cubes from the UI. The idea is to make the brick patterns dynamic, and receive brick data (i.e. positions) from a .json file. I've taken the approach of populating using Instantiate and a prefab, although I'm not sure how to incorporate that with data from .json or if I'm on the right track. Newbie here please help! Even just directing me to concepts would be fantastic.

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BrickGrid : MonoBehaviour 
   {

```
public Transform brickPrefab;
private Vector3[] BrickCoords; 
private int totalBricks;


void Start()
{
    totalBricks = 4;
    BrickCoords = new Vector3[totalBricks];

    BrickCoords[0] = new Vector3(-2.2f, 2f, 0f);
    BrickCoords[1] = new Vector3(-0.75f, 2f, 0f);
    BrickCoords[2] = new Vector3(0.75f, 2f, 0f);
    BrickCoords[3] = new Vector3(2.2f, 2f, 0f);

    for (int x = 0; x < totalBricks; x++)
    {

        Instantiate(brickPrefab, BrickCoords[x], Quaternion.identity);

    }

}

public static void initGrid(){

}
```

}

```
 [System.Serializable]
 public class BrickCoordinate
 {
     public Vector3 brickPos;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your JsonString looks. But something along these lines might be what you need:

Make a class containing a list of blocks.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Bricks
{
   public List<BrickCoordinate> BrickCoordinates;
}
```

Then load in your json from wherever you have it, and pass it into Unity's JsonUtility class.

```
var listOfBlocks = JsonUtility.FromJson<Bricks>(yourJsonStringHere);
```

And then you can iterate over your list and instantiate each item.

You can view more info [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JsonUtility.FromJson.html)

Edit:

An easy way to get a correct Json string, is to do the exact opposite.
Use the Json function in your code to test and serialize a list of blocks.
(Also i changed the name of the list, because it was misleading)

```
var test = new Bricks
{
   BrickCoordinates = new List<BrickCoordinate>
   {
      new BrickCoordinate
      {
          brickpos = new Vector3{ x = 1, y = 2, z = 3};
      },
      new BrickCoordinate
      {
          brickpos = new Vector3{ x = 2, y = 2, z = 3};
      },
      new BrickCoordinate
      {
          brickpos = new Vector3{ x = 1, y = 4, z = 3};
      },
   }
};



var jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(test);
Debug.Log(jsonString);
```

Comment: I think I understand Json Utility and loading in json data, however I don't understand how to create the json data. Does this make any sense?  


    {
     "Bricks" : [
    
          { "brickPos": { 
            "x": -2.2,
            "y": 2,
        "z": 0}
       },{"brickPos": {
        "x": -0.75,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 0}
       }
     ]
    }

Comment: `{
 "Bricks" : [

  { "brickPos": { 
    "x": -2.2,
    "y": 2,
    "z": 0}
  },{"brickPos": {
    "x": -0.75,
    "y": 2,
    "z": 0}
   }
 ]
}`

Comment: @Immortality rly appreciate your help!